# Insert a new row in Sheet 2 for each cell in a range in Sheet 1 that is not empty

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Hi I'm new to the Google Sheets App Script and not sure where to start. I'm trying to write a Script that will insert a new row in Sheet 2 for each cell in a range in Sheet 1 that is not empty.

For example, in Sheet 1 range C2:E6, there are 4 cells that are not empty - C2, D3, C4, E4.

[image]

In Sheet 2, there should be 4 newly inserted rows with the corresponding Account & Owner column values, and transpose the Product & Quantity values into column C & D.

Sheet 1            - >          Sheet 2

Row 2: A2+B2+C1+C2 -> Row 2: A2+B2+C2+D2

Row 3: A3+B3+D1+D3 -> Row 3: A3+B3+C3+D3

Row 4: A4+B4+C1+C4 -> Row 4: A4+B4+C4+D4

Row 4: A4+B4+E1+E4 -> Row 5: A5+B5+C5+D5

[image]

As for Row 5&6 in Sheet 1, they don't have cells in the red range that have values so no need to insert new rows in Sheet 2.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). In the event the results in Sheet2 do not need to be editable, but are for viewing only, you can do that with a plain vanilla spreadsheet formula. Please [edit] your question and explain _why_ you are asking for a script.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se].  Please take the [Tour] and read [ask].  *"I'm new to the Google Sheets App Script and not sure where to start"*  You should start with 1.  [Google Apps Script](https://www.google.com/script/start/)  2. [Apps Script samples overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples) 3.  [Automate & extend Google Workspace with simple code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)  You can also find example [tag:google-apps-script] questions here and on [so].  If you run into a problem let us know and we'd be happy to help.